# Оптимизация читаемости кода СИ

Tags: c, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

начал изучение СИ, вообщем написал программу которая генерирует одну матрицу, находит в ней max и min и использует их для генерации другой матрицы по правилу. Программа работает отлично, но мне хочется узнать свои ошибки в плане читаемости кода и компактности, может я чего лишнего написал или не читабельно для других?
Подскажите пожалуйста, просто хочется сразу приучиться писать читаемый код для других людей.Так же если не сложно может программу как то проще можно было сделать?
(P.S больше всего интересует правильно скобки расставляю или по другому надо как то?)
Спасибо сразу!

Оптимизированный код 2.0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 3
#define N 4
void main()
{
    int i, j, o, p, array1[M][N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    //Создание первой матрицы
    for (i = 0; i<M; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<N; ++j)
        {
            array1[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            printf("%d\t", array1[i][j]);               //Вывод на экран первой матрицы
        }   printf("\n");
    }
    //Вычисление минимального и максимального элемента в первой матрице
    int min = array1[0][0];
    int max = array1[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            if (max<array1[i][j])
            {
                max = array1[i][j];
            }
            if (min>array1[i][j])
            {
                min = array1[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("min=%d\n", min);
    printf("max=%d\n", max);

    int array2[M][N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    //Создание второй матрицы по правилу(строка 52)
    for (o = 0; o<M; ++o)
    {
        for (p = 0; p<N; ++p)
        {
            array2[o][p] = (2 * array1[o][p] + min) / max;
            printf("%d\t", array2[o][p]);                //Вывод на экран второй матрицы
        }   printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info

Comment: Слишком много у вас одинаковых циклов. Типичные подзадачи(aka вывод матрицы и т.п.) стоит выносить в функции. Мин/макс можно искать одновременно.

Comment: у вас кстати в строке объявления переменных `int i....` получилось слово `jopa`. Не стесняйтесь давать переменным понятные названия: например, не `a`, a `array`, иначе в большой программе получите то самое слово. Пишите свои функции, не стоит весь код запихивать в main. Размерность NxY на мой взгляд - не комильфо. Пусть будет NxM, а (X,Y,Z) обычно координаты. Переменные для итерации циклов в этом случае лучше (наверно) объявлять внутри цикла: `for(int i=0;...` но это не точно.

Comment: @de_frag  Понял, принял щас попробую сделать: функции, мин/макс одновременно, нормально назвать переменные. Спасибо!

Comment: @de_frag Вообще поработал над кодом) Использовать функции не стал так как тут и так всего 50 строк, думаю с функциями в такой маленькой программе тоже самое будет, но для больших программ обязательно буду использовать. Вообщем можете посмотреть) (P.S отредактировал пост)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> правильно скобки расставляю или по другому надо как то?

Вообще-то, рекомендаций (и даже - стандартов) на оформление кода программы существует очень много. Предполагаю, что в каждой софтверной компании есть свой СТП.

Я бы рекомендовал (для начала) ознакомится с рекомендациями, изложенными в документе:

*GNU Coding Standards* (http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html)

Там много чего написано полезного. Есть там и раздел про скобки:

*5.1. Formatting Your Source Code*

Писал его Ричард Столлмен в Бог знает каком году, так что с тех пор много чего изменилось.

Но лично моя рекомендация: если наниматель не требует соблюдения определённого стандарта, пишите так как ВАМ нравится! :-)